# Create shapefile based on geojson data with geotools (Java)

Tags: shapefile, geojson, java, geotools

I'm using Geotools 14.0 for Java and I'm trying to generate shapefile based on data from GeoJSON. Here is my code:

```
try {
        String url = "geojson.json";
        File geojson = new File(url);

        File shpFile = new File("test.shp");
        ShapefileDataStoreFactory dataStoreFactory = new ShapefileDataStoreFactory();

        Map<String, Serializable> params = new HashMap<String, Serializable>();
        params.put("url", shpFile.toURI().toURL());
        params.put("create spatial index", Boolean.TRUE);

        ShapefileDataStore shpDataStore = (ShapefileDataStore) dataStoreFactory.createNewDataStore(params);

        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(geojson);
        int decimals = 15;
        GeometryJSON gjson = new GeometryJSON(decimals);
        FeatureJSON fjson = new FeatureJSON(gjson);

        FeatureCollection<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> fc = fjson.readFeatureCollection(in);

        SimpleFeatureType type = (SimpleFeatureType) fc.getSchema();

        shpDataStore.createSchema(type);
        Transaction transaction = new DefaultTransaction("create");

        String typeName = shpDataStore.getTypeNames()[0];

        SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = shpDataStore.getFeatureSource(typeName);

        if (featureSource instanceof FeatureStore) {
            SimpleFeatureStore featureStore = (SimpleFeatureStore) featureSource;

            featureStore.setTransaction(transaction);
            try {

                featureStore.addFeatures(fc);
                for(Object c : featureStore.getFeatures().toArray()){
                    System.out.println("C: " + ((SimpleFeatureImpl)c).toString());
                }
                transaction.commit();                    
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                transaction.rollback();

            } finally {
                transaction.close();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println(typeName + " does not support read/write access");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "Exception " + e.getLocalizedMessage();
    }
```

And after this, i get test.shp file but it does not contain any geometry data. If I convert it back to geojson I get this:

> ```
> {   "type": "Feature",   "properties": {   },   "id": "test.1" }
> ```

And this is my original geojson file (geojson.json):

> > ```
> > {
> >   "type": "FeatureCollection",
> >   "features": [
> >     {
> >       "properties": {
> >         "version": 0
> >       },
> >       "id": "1",
> >       "type": "Feature",
> >       "geometry": {
> >         "type": "Polygon",
> >         "coordinates": [
> >           [
> >             [
> >               1868732.467515988,
> >               6594375.3042187244
> >             ],
> >             [
> >               1868732.467515988,
> >               5165920.1196253505
> >             ],
> >             [
> >               3297187.6521093622,
> >               5165920.1196253505
> >             ],
> >             [
> >               3297187.6521093622,
> >               6594375.3042187244
> >             ],
> >             [
> >               1868732.467515988,
> >               6594375.3042187244
> >             ]
> >           ]
> >         ]
> >       }
> >     }
> >   ]       }
> > ```

Is there any way to do this in a proper way?

Comment: what happens if you rename your geometry to the_geom ?

Comment: what do you mean? where could I rename it, in the geojson.json file or somewhere else?

Comment: in the json file

Comment: I tried that and then I got null pointer exception on shpDataStore.createSchema(type);

Comment: OK I'll see if I can find time to test later

Comment: Did you have a chance to take a look? I need that urgently, so thats why I'm asking...

Comment: if it is urgent you should consider purchasing commercial support

Comment: I also use GeoTools 14.0 and I have tried using the following code, but when I run it gives me the following error "Error while parsing JAI registry files"file:/C:/Users/..../Desktop/geotools-14.0/imageio-ext-imagereadmt-1.1M012010.jar!/META-INF/registryFile.jai" :
Error in registry file at line number # 29
A descriptor is already registered against the name "ImageReadMT" under registry mode "rendered"
java.lang.NullPointerException
at test.WriteShapefile.writeFeatures (WriteShapefile.java:108) **--->** **GeometryDescriptor schema.getGeometryDescriptor geom = ();
at test.JsonParsing.main (Json

Comment: PS. I work with this file musei.json : https://www.dati.lombardia.it/Cultura/Musei-riconosciuti-da-Regione-Lombardia/3syc-54zf

Comment: This does not answer the question. If you have a new one, please ask it.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/83631)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: Your feature type doesn't match the Shapefile standard so the illegal bits get dropped by GeoTools. I have a [utility class](https://gitlab.com/snippets/9275) to fix this -

```
try {
        String url = "geojson.json";
        File geojson = new File(url);

        File shpFile = new File("test.shp");
        ShapefileDataStoreFactory dataStoreFactory = new ShapefileDataStoreFactory();

        Map<String, Serializable> params = new HashMap<String, Serializable>();
        params.put("url", shpFile.toURI().toURL());
        params.put("create spatial index", Boolean.TRUE);

        /*
         * ShapefileDataStore shpDataStore = (ShapefileDataStore)
         * dataStoreFactory.createNewDataStore(params);
         */
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(geojson);
        int decimals = 15;
        GeometryJSON gjson = new GeometryJSON(decimals);
        FeatureJSON fjson = new FeatureJSON(gjson);

        FeatureCollection<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> fc = fjson.readFeatureCollection(in);
        fc.getSchema();

        WriteShapefile writer = new WriteShapefile(shpFile);
        writer.writeFeatures(fc);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        // return "Exception " + e.getLocalizedMessage();
    }
```

Long answer: Shapefiles suck as a format! The first attribute in every feature must be the geometry and it must be called `the_geom` (hence my earlier suggestion to change the name of your geometry attribute). As featuretypes are immutable in GeoTools it is necessary to loop through the attributes and rename the geometry and then move it to first place while creating a new schema. DataUtilities.retype will reorder the attributes to match the new schema but as the geometry has changed name you have to copy the yourself. Then you can write the shapefile out as normal.

Comment: It works now. Thank you very much, I didn't know these things about attribute ordering - I had no idea that SHP is that strict about that.

Comment: Feel free to upvote the answer if it helped you